# Getting ImportError: cannot import name pformat when running Flask App. I am using Python 2.7.13 and have flask installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, importerror

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "This is the homepage"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

While running this flask program in IDLE, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Arnav/Documents/flaskpractice.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    from werkzeug.routing import Map, Rule, RequestRedirect, BuildError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 103, in <module>
    from pprint import pformat
ImportError: cannot import name pformat
```

I am using Python 2.7.13 and I have flask installed. I tried googling the error but didn't get a fix. Please help me

Comment: Did you install flask using virtualenv or globally?

Comment: I think I installed it globally - using 'sudo pip install flask'

Comment: I would recommend using virtualenv instead setting it up globally. Maybe you have some conflicts between packages or anything else. I just tested it in virtualenv and it runs nicely from IDLE, although I don't use IDLE.

Comment: Just tried that out. Even after installing flask in the virtual environment I get an 'ImportError: No module named flask' error message

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a flask app from virtualenv you can create a file `run_idle.py` file and launch it from the same directory as your flask app. Put this into `run_idle.py` and run it using `python run_idle.py`:

```
from idlelib.PyShell import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It will run IDLE from the virtualenv so that it will see that flask is installed. Note that you need to activate virtualenv before running IDLE using:

```
. env/bin/activate
```

Comment: is there any way to fix the error without using virtualenv?

Comment: @ArnavAgrawal Virtualenv is a more recommended ywa of doing that. It allows you avoid to messing up your python packages on your system and keep them separate for each project. Probably you've installed a lot of stuff globally and this might be the reason of your problem.